# Sum specific columns in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with 100 columns. I want to calculate the sum for column 4 to n. I could generate the sum for a single column but when I try it for all columns I fail. Here is what I have so far

```
import decimal
import numpy as np
import os as os
import csv as csv
import re as re
import sys

col=10
values=[]
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = reader.next()
    for line in reader:
    #print line
        line = [int(i) for i in line]
    col_totals = [sum(result) for result in zip(*line)]
    print col_totals
       #values.append(int(line[col]))
       #csum=sum(values)
    #print csum
```

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want to compute the sum for columns 4-10, for each row? Or do you want to compute the sum of column 4 over all rows and column 5 over all rows, etc?

Comment: Have you tried `reduce` as it's explained [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce).

Comment: Yes I want to compute the sum of column 4 over all rows and column 5 over all rows, etc?

Answer (score 1):

this is very, very easy in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
df[df.columns[4:]].sum()
```

and if you want a per-line sum of the columns, it's this:

```
df[df.columns[4:]].sum(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum across contiguous lines, this will do

```
i, j = 3, 5

with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = reader.next()
    table = list(reader)
    sums = [sum(float(elt) for elt in col) for col in zip(*table)[i:j]]
```

try also the following

```
requested = [4, 7, 12, 13, 21, 81]

with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = reader.next()
    table = list(reader)
    sums = [sum(float(elt) for elt in col) for i, col in enumerate(zip(*table)) if i in requested]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. However when I try this i get TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @learnincurve I had tested my solution with a _synthetic_ tabelle before posting, merrily oblivious of the Sad Truth that `csv.reader` only returns strings.  Oh, my bad! I'll learn `pandas` one day or another...